# How can I increase the size of the open pole ocirc?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, circuitikz

How can I increase the size of the open pole `ocirc` without affecting other components? 
There is  `\ctikzset{nodes width=0.15}` in the manual but this would also increase  the size of ocirc in the switch.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american, siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

\ctikzset{nodes width=0.15}
\draw (0,5) node[ocirc] at (0,5){} to [I] ++ (2,0) to [cute closing switch] ++(2,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @SimonDispa oh, I have been trying all methods with nodes width and couldn't make it work. Turns out it is much simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can draw a regular circle and set the `inner sep` manually. This is similar to the example of drawing colored dots in section 4.19.3 *Styling transformer's coils independently* in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf) (in the current 1.6.0 version this is on page 131).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american, siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

\draw (0,5) node[circle, draw, fill=white, inner sep=3pt] at (0,5){} to [I] ++ (2,0) to [cute closing switch] ++(2,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and SimonDispa just mentioned scale too. I probably should check TikZ first instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can also define new "poles specifiers" like these:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

% you seems to like big poles...
\tikzset{% this definition is at tikz level, because
    % it will be used with a `node[... ]` element
        bigO/.style={ocirc, circuitikz/nodes width=0.1},
    }
\ctikzset{% define new poles style
    O-/.style={bipole nodes={bigO}{none}},
    O-O/.style={bipole nodes={bigO}{bigO}},
    -O/.style={bipole nodes={none}{bigO}},
}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [I, O-] ++(2,0) 
        to [cute closing switch,-O] ++(2,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, I was wondering if we could make a copy and modify it.